# Generate random Double between -x and x

Tags: java, random, double, range

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random number in a range with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-number-in-a-range-with-java)

```
double x = //Random number between -0.5 and 0.5
```

Possible Outputs:

```
-0.23
0.01
0.26
-0.4
```

How do I generate a double between the range of (example) `-0.5` and `0.5`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it

```
Math.random() - 0.5
```

`Math.random` will generate betweeen `0` and `1`. If you want between `-0.5` and `+0.5` then you can just `-0.5` from this result. See the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)

One thing that this will not do is ever give you `0.5` as `Math.random()` does never return `1`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363732/846476) post will give you more details and a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks all, but this was the easiest one for what I needed :)

Comment: @Baz okay thanks for explaination. So it cant return 0.5 or -0.5. Anyways it's not a big deal in my case. Thanks!

Comment: @user1621988 You should thank RNJ, since he posted this answer. To be exact: it **can** result in `-0.5`, it **cannot** result in `0.5`.

Answer (score 20):

```
return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
```